# Using php to pop an array stack (or iterate through a text file) on a timed interval

Tags: php

I want to set up a small php script which simply returns a string, either from an array or from a line in a text file. As well as returning the string any time this script is called, I also want it to automatically cycle through the set of items (either an array or each line in a text file) on a timed basis. For example, every 15 minutes I want the script to step through each item in the list. I've not actually done anything like this before, so i'd be interested to hear any advice. Thanks

Comment: We'd need to know a lot more about how this is expected to work and whether you have admin rights on the system where the script is to be deployed. You say that you need this processing to occur driven by time intervals - but the nature of web development is that your script takes some action when it receives a request from a client. Can you elucidate?

Comment: This script is part of an application which will be run on a LAN in a controlled space, where I will have admin rights to the system. What you've mentioned is exactly what I'm unsure about - whether or not i can use php's time functions (like sleep()) to continue manipulating the contents of a file over a fixed period of time (3 hours). The script will also be getting called by a client app (Adobe Director) every 30 secs or so, where it will be returning the current element from the file. Hope this makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CRON JOBS. If you have admin rights then you can easily set up cron jobs to run your scripts by second,minute hour or day. Just add your script to a cron tab along with the intervals. Look below for instructions

http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

As for the PHP script i guess you must have found it out by now.